# How to remove Android Permissions which were added by a NuGet Library in Xamarin Project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions

When a cross platform nuget package is used in a Xamarin project, it may add some permissions to the Android Manifest at build time (i.e. you do not have to change the Manifest.xml in your Android project). This is often useful. When the package is well designed, it only adds permissions which are needed for it to work properly.

But sometimes it adds to much permissions. It even might add permissions you have to explain the usage to pass the review. Is it possible to prevent these permissions are added by the package? Or to remove it in a post processing?

(of course, in case of open source projects it is possible to remove the nuget and replace it by the source code and manipulate it. but this is not a very comfortable solution)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to mark an XML Node as "to be removed" by adding the attribute tools:node="remove" in your apps Manifest.xml file of the Android project.

Example:

Let's say the nuget library adds the "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION".

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
 ....
</manifest>
```

Credits goes to [houman.sanati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64844299/2427749)